# Store a data record into another table if it does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a SQL code that is doing the following thing:

1. `SELECT * FROM fzs_contest WHERE answer = 'D' order by rand() limit 1;`
2. Store the result of the code above to the table *fzs_contest_winners* (create the table if it does not exist)
3. If the data record already exists in the table *fzs_contest_winners*, reapeat line #1 until it is unique.

Is that possible with SQL only?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your table structures? What's the final result that you're looking for? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

How about just getting a valid winner the first time?

```
insert into fzs_contest_winners ( . . .)
    select . . . 
    from fzs_contest c
    where answer = 'D' and
          not exists (select 1 from fzs_context_winners cw where cw.?? = c.??)
    order by rand()
    limit 1;
```

The `??` is for the column that identifies someone as being the same in the two tables.

Note:  This type of query *could* choose the same winner twice, if two threads were running at the same time.  However, it seems unlikely to me that you are selecting more than one winner at a time.  In addition, you should guarantee that a person only appears once in the table by using a unique index.